# Is there any plug-in or add-on available in eclipse to Check/(set own rules if any) C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, coding-style

Please suggest............
..

Answer (score 1):

I found this when searching for generic static checking (no idea what the current state is): http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis

Answer (score 1):

There is cppcheck

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page
http://code.google.com/p/cppcheclipse/

I have played with the cppcheck and its quite good, though not as complete as checkstyle or pmd are for Java.  I have not used the eclipse plugin though.